# Best way to handle images into the Database

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

It's my first time having to design a web app that has to think about image upload / Download traffic & also using Amazon web servers. I've been reading around but I am still pretty confuse on how best to tackle my issues.

I am building a web app that will have significant traffic with images and I've noticed that `Amazon RDS` is cheaper than `Amazon S3`. Normally in the websites that I am used to build I don't need to worry about local storage vs db storage.

Would I be loosing anything by storing all the pics in the db instead of local (S3)?

This then lead me to think that it would be best to storage the images in the `Amazon RDS`. As a result of that I wonder:

The user will upload 4 images in general: `mainPicThumb`, `mainPic`, `secondPic` and `secondPicThumb`. Each one will also have the fields `name` and `size`. For efficiency should I put each picture type in a different table or it shouldn't make an issue? I mean, if I separate the pictures in different tables would I gain quicker access speed and search speed or gain anything?

also most users queries will return 10 different Thumb images

I am building my backend with PHP and using an ORM ( Propel ).

I would appreciate any guidance / advice.

Comment: S3 is definitely cheaper than RDS for storage - it's only a few cents (5 percent to be precise) at lowest tier but increases with total storage. Also it performs far better and is natively integrated with CloudFront.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I/O its a lot cheaper for RDS $0.11 per 1 million requests vs $0.005 per  1,000 requests. its the main difference.

Comment: S3 is $0.004 per 10.000 - you're looking at the PUT pricing, not GET. Also I can't find the RDS pricing you mention, it's charged per hour, not per request. You'd still incur cost elsewhere to actually serve the content over the internet. A dedicated file storage and serving service is *definitely* not more expensive than abusing a relational DBMS to do a similar task.

Comment: http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/ here is the RDS pricing. Still the 0.005$/million beats the 0.004$/10.000. Unless as you mentioned there are other costs on other sides and it just look cheaper but it actually isnt

Comment: I see the problem - you're mistaking IO pricing for external requests. [That's very wrong](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34352/22493). The IO cost is just the base cost of having a database, and the strain you put on its underlying storage. You'll still incur costs elsewhere for actually invoking the DB, transferring the data, and processing the requests, most probably via EC2.

Comment: I posted a full answer based on this discussion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You made some fundamental calculation errors in calculating your costs. Storing data in a relational database is never, ever, going to be cheaper than storing it in a completely optimized flat data storage system.

When storing data in S3, you will only ever be billed by actual storage usage, and actual network usage. That's the precise amount of data, averaged over the entire month, at $0.095 per GB/mth (lower tiers apply starting at 1TB/mth), plus $0.004 per 10000 external GET requests, plus $0.120 per GB data transfer to the internet (lower tiers apply starting at 10TB/mth).

When storing data in RDS, you pay an hourly fee for the instance, plus $0.125 per GB/mth for storage, plus a cost per IO operation on the underlying storage. A single query, requesting megabytes of binary data, could easily trigger hundreds or thousands of IO operations - or none, if the result happens to be cached. It's very hard to predict IO usage, except that it has no linear relation by definition to the amount of queries executed and the amount of data transferred. As a guideline, I just checked a LAMP server, at about 0.60 load since it's the middle of the night, and it's continuously processing about 50~150 IO operations per second on its storage disk (OS, swap and /tmp are on another), while barely doing anything.

For data stored in RDS, actually retrieving the data only means that you have transferred it to your EC2 instance or another means of accessing it. You will then still incur full costs for actually processing requests and transferring the data onwards to the internet from there.

Summarizing: storing data in RDS instead of S3 will always be more expensive. It's just hard to predict whether it'll be 10, 100 or 1000 times as expensive. Use S3 for storing files, that's what the Simple Storage Service is for. It will also be far, ***FAR*** more performant, especially if you bind it to CloudFront to utilize its caching edge locations.

(all prices mentioned assume cheapest Amazon locations - prices may vary slightly elsewhere)

Answer (score 8):

I have architected solutions on AWS for Stock photography sites which stores millions of images spanning TB's, would like to share some of the best practice in AWS for your requirement:

P1) Store the Original Image file in S3 Standard option

P2) Store the reproducible images like thumbs etc in the S3 Reduced Redundancy option (RRS) to save costs

P3) Meta data about images including the S3 URL can be stored in Amazon RDS or Amazon DynamoDB depending upon the query complexity. Query the entries from Amazon RDS. If your query is complex it is also common practice to Store the meta data in Amazon CloudSearch or Apache Solr.

P4) Deliver your thumbs to users with low latency using Amazon CloudFront.

Comment: Good suggestions, thanks for the insightful answer. I wouldn't have thought myself of the standard/RRS distinction and only using CF for the thumbs but that makes sense obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Storing images in a SQL database is *possible* but not considered best practice.

On the other hand, if you really want to store images in the database, some databases have better support for file storage. For example, [CouchDB](https://couchdb.apache.org/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and [Riak](http://basho.com/riak/).

It's a tradeoff: the upside is that your development is more "portable" because you can develop/test without incurring Amazon costs. The downside is that you are on the hook for scaling when it grows.

Most people would rather take advantage of S3, and keep a minimum amount of metadata about the images in a database.

> For efficiency should I put each picture type in a different table or it shouldn't make an issue?

If you think that your thumbnail sizes are fixed, you can store one row per image, then generate all variants in code. (i.e. pic123/orig.jpg pic123/small.jpg, pic123/medium.jpg)

If you think you may add sizes infrequently, then make columns for each size. (i.e. insert into images values (name='pic123', 'orig'='y', 'small'='y').)